# How to regroup the map keys in java7

Tags: java, java-7

I have a map which has elements like

```
aCol0:"Acolvalue0"
cCol0:"Ccolvalue0"
bCol1:"Bcolvalue1"
aCol1:"Acolvalue1"
bCol0:"Bcolvalue0"
cCol1:"Ccolvalue1"
```

After adding these elements in a Treemap it was sorted this way

```
aCol0:"Acolvalue0"
aCol1:"Acolvalue1"
bCol0:"Bcolvalue0"
bCol1:"Bcolvalue1"
cCol0:"Ccolvalue0"
cCol1:"Ccolvalue1"
```

But i want to regroup the map keys like this:

```
aCol0:"Acolvalue0"
bCol0:"Bcolvalue0"
cCol0:"Ccolvalue0"

aCol1:"Acolvalue1"
bCol1:"Bcolvalue1"
cCol1:"Ccolvalue1"
```

Please suggest how to achieve this.

Thanks,
Asha

Comment: You'll need to write a Comparator which sorts the keys the way you want, instead of using the natural ordering.

Comment: And hint: this is really a "solved" problem. There are literally dozens, if not hundreds of questions around here that (or tutorials on the web) that tell you how to do custom sorting in Java, even with a focus for TreeSets.